# How to change PHP file icon set to open with Notepad++

Tags: windows, notepad++, icons

I just installed Notepad++ and opened a PHP file using "Open with", I then checked off

> Always use selected program to open this kind of file

in Windows. The file has a notepad icon. How can I change this icon to a custom one?

**Update:**
The files with regular notepad icons are on a secondary drive not my `C:` drive. I just looked at PHP files on my `C:` drive and they have the association. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: when you use the Windows "choose program" or "open with" to assign associations, it always chooses a weird default icon. Try doing associations in the native program's settings.

Comment: I also tried going to Tools - Folder Options - File Types, and set all PHP files to use Notepad++ but they still have the default windows notepad icon.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you'd probably have to edit the registry or download a program that basically edits the registry for you.  Here's an example: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/57455-file-extension-icon-change-default-icon.html

Comment: Not sure what the problem was but started working after changing the file types in Windows for CSS, JS as well as the settings in Notepad++ something wasn't refreshing but took affect and now I have the icons.